# How to fix "Project with ID "some id" doesn't exist" Django FileField model error

Tags: python, django

I have a model which I can edit from admin page. I want to upload the file, then download the file back.

In models:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_content = models.TextField()
    project_published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default=datetime.now())
    project_file = models.FileField(default="Null",upload_to='Files')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_title
```

In admin:

```py
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ["project_title",
    #          "project_published",
    #          "project_content", 
    #          "project_funded",]

    fieldsets = [
        ("Title/date", {"fields": ["project_title", "project_published"]}),
        ("URL", {"fields":["project_slug"]})

        ("Content", {"fields":["project_content", "project_file"]}),

    ]
```

FileField generates 2 sub-fields: an upload button, and a "current" field with the link to the current file if one exists.

[image]

File upload works just fine, and the file is stored in "Files" directory, but when I click the link I get redirected to homepage and get the "Project with ID "1/change/Files/somefilename" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?" error.

I have tried adding to admin:

```py
def file_link(self, Project):
        if Project.project_file:
            return "<a href='%s' download>Download</a>" % (Project.project_file.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"
    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'
```

but it just prints the href as plain text, containing the "Files/somefilename" url.

[image]

Last requests handled by the server:

[10/Oct/2019 15:57:15] "GET /admin/main/project/1/change/Files/61765395_604632376708720_5004719923088326656_n_1_zAanPtO.jpg HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[10/Oct/2019 15:57:15] "GET /admin/main/project/1/change/Files/61765395_604632376708720_5004719923088326656_n_1_zAanPtO.jpg/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Oct/2019 15:57:15] "GET /admin/main/project/1/change/Files/61765395_604632376708720_5004719923088326656_n_1_zAanPtO.jpg/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Oct/2019 15:57:15] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7848

Comment: you need to mark_safe the href : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe , but can you share the full error stacktrace? Also can you please share what kind of processing server does and what is the code for it?

Comment: Tried mark_safe now, it started a download, but for some reason it just downloaded the raw html of the front page instead of my file. There is no stacktrace, as i just get redirected to the homepage and get the error message as a popup. Also, There are no changes to the file yet, I will clarify my post.

Comment: http code 301/302 means it has been redirected. Means file has been deleted(probably), can you share the code where the changes happen in file?

Comment: I haven't written any code that modifies the file, as I try to figure the upload/download first. This is literally the only part that affects the file, but I do not know if the server does something to the file while saving it. But as far as I can tell, the file is in "myproject\Files\", with the exact same name.

Comment: The url to the file porvided by FileField , which the href accesses is "/admin/main/project/1/change/Files/filename", if this helps

Comment: did you configure the media url properly?

Comment: I am not sure, I have followed the instructions here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/ and i have MEDIA_ROOT = '/Files/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to fix the [**`MEDIA_URL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL) like this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And add the media url in urls.py to allow django serve your media files([**`in development server`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```